# No visible tags to enter username or password when scraping webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've been trying to enter my username & password into this webpage but I am struggling to see how to do this. I've researched `li` tags, I've tried to loop forID's and all sorts but the best I can do is change the word "username:" and change the word "password:"

I would be greatful to have some pointers that will push me in the right direction.

```
Sub Coles()


    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("https://www.supplierportal.coles.com.au/wps/portal")

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

    For Each ele In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
        If InStr(ele.innerText, "Login") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print ele
            ele.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' code to enter username

    ' code to enter password

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim url As String

    url = "https://www.supplierportal.coles.com.au/wps/myportal/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zivbycnS19LE0NDSz8DQw8PYIDjMzdzI2CLc31wwkpiAJKG-AAjgZA_VFgJThNMIQqwGNGQW6EQaajoiIAOpTxFw!!/dz/d5/L0lDU1EvUU5RSy9ZTFlB/"
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate url

    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

    IE.document.getElementById("Ecom_User_ID").Value = "Sid"
    IE.document.getElementById("Ecom_Password").Value = "MyPassword"
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I am pre-emting your next question "How do I click the Login button?"

Since there is only one form, this will do the job

```
IE.document.forms(0).submit
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Also I appreciate the edit with the login button code. I would have tried myself and if failed would have asked here.. and to be honest I did do a bit of looking for it and was struggling.. Sincerely appreciate the assistance.

Comment: I just found this that may be helpful for any future viewers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8